# Why does ACL have permission restrictions?

Tags: permissions, dropbox, acl

I am using the dropbox client on my ubuntu. I have a need for user www-data to be able to create files inside folders created by user dropbox. I configured using ACLs to inherit permissions rwx for group **dropbox**, which user www-data belongs to, but when I check the permissions of the newly created Test folder by user dropbox

```
getfacl Test
```

I see effective group restrictions.

```
# file: Test
# owner: dropbox
# group: dropbox
user::rwx
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
group:dropbox:rwx               #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:dropbox:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

As far as I understand, this is related to lines:

```
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

or

```
default:other::r-x
```

I can see the contents of the folders and can navigate among them, but I cannot create new files. How can I configure that this limitation is not?

Comment: That is correct. That line says no write access.

Comment: What can cause this restriction to permissions since I did not configure it manually?